# Universal Links work in simulator but not on real devices

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-universal-links

I added the apple-app-site-association: <domain>/.well-known/apple-app-site-association
I started with the "applinks" and when that didn't work I also added webcredentials and activitycontinuation.

I enabled Associated Domains for this app id and in the project I added applinks:<domain>, applinks:m.<domain> & applinks:*.<domain> in the associated domains which now appear in the entitlements file.

I checked the domain in the apple validation tool https://search.developer.apple.com/appsearch-validation-tool/ and that worked.

I tested it on multiple simulators and in each of them I could go to the website in safari and it showed me the banner above, I also sent a fake message in the Messages and that showed the details and opened the app.

I also tried changing Deployment Target to iOS 10.

But when I try to install it on the device from xCode, either in debug or release configuration or even upload the build to test flight, this doesn't work (Tried on iPhone 5s, iPhone 8 & iPhone XR).

I searched the internet and saw many people saying that universal links did not work for them until they did this and that and I tried every thing they said but I still can't make it work on real devices.

Is there something else I should do to make this work or did I get something wrong?

Comment: Hey did you ever figure this out?

Comment: I actually left the company years ago so I'm not sure whats the status on that (pretty sure it never was fixed), but I want to try what Manish suggested, hopefully soon.

Answer (score 1):

You have to wait a bit ( from minutes to hours ) after your app is successfully installed and launched to let iOS fetch the associated domain.

You can use a proxy like `Charles` to check if iOS has make the call.

Comment: Hi, thanks for that but when I used Charles I saw that it got the AASA after a few seconds and still nothing would suggest the app for this url.

Comment: How are you testing ?

Comment: I used Charles proxy as you suggested, I started by testing the connection using the link in safari to see that it works and also https work and then I installed the application. It took a few second but it made the request and I saw the aasa contents.

Comment: Universal links don't work in safari. You can test via notes / mail / messages

Comment: I also test via gmail, notes and messages, the result was the same.
But as far as I know this also should work in safari, in the simulator after I install the app I can go to the website and pull down to reveal the banner that suggests me to open it in the app

Answer (score 0):

Got the same issue and fixed by replacing App ID prefix instead of team ID in apple-app-site-association file